# Change text without affecting other attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this double drop down list

```
<div class="container" id = "chooseTables">

  <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">please choose tables <span class="caret"></span></button>

     <ul class="dropdown-menu">

       <li class="dropdown-submenu">
       <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">table for 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class = "select" id = "table1" ><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><align = "middle">-----table1-----</a></li>
       <li class = "select" id = "table2" ><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><align = "middle">-----table2-----</a></li>
       <li class = "select" id = "table3" ><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><align = "middle">-----table3-----</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Every time the server send me some info I want to update text content in those `<li>`tags.

ie.

```
var room = document.getElementsByClassName("select")

    room[1].textContent = "vacant"
```

But I could not change only the text without affecting its attributes like `align` and `href`

I tried `textContent` and `childNodes[0].nodeValue` they did not really work.

Here is fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/TU4FB/135/

Comment: What is <align = "middle"> in your code

Comment: try to align the text to middle..@brk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
room[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent = "11"
or
room[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getElementsByTagName('align')[0].textContent = "11"
```